# Sending the data to the server through post when internet connection comes back

Tags: android, json, parsing

In my application, i am sending the data to the server through post method in json format.
Here you can see my code.

```
JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject();
        object1.put("homesafe_events_version", "1.0");

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("PhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
        object.put("EventTypeID", Integer.parseInt(eventTypeId));
        object.put("FreeFromText", "");
        object.put("EventTime", eventTime );
        object.put("Latitude", latitude);
        object.put("Longitude", longitude);
        object.put("Altitude", Double.parseDouble(df.format(altitude)));
        object.put("HorizAccuracy",Double.parseDouble(df.format(horizAccuracy)));
        object.put("VertAccuracy", vertiAccuracy);
        object.put("Speed", speed);
        object.put("Heading", Double.parseDouble(df.format(heading)));
        object.put("BatteryStatus", batteryStatus);

        object1.put("Event", object);

        String str = object1.toString();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String encodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        List<NameValuePair> value = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        value.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", encodedURL));

        // UrlEncodedFormEntity entity=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(value);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(str, "UTF8");
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
```

Every thing is working properly.There is a button in my app.On clicking that button,some values are calculated and pass in the parameters to send them to server.Now suppose the internet is not available and i pressed that button for 5 times then in this case all the values which was calculated 5 times are stored in somewhere else and when the connection comes the web service will hit and all the data will be sent to the server.This is my actual problem.Please suggest me what to do.Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: You have to check if net connection not available , store it in local database , and register a receiver to check network connection, and when it receive network notification then post data to server from receiver

Comment: can u please provide me a sample code??

Answer (score 3):

You can create a database and store those values there. Now after sending those value you must remove them from you database.

Now , create a broadcast class that always check the network status.When network comes it will check that db and send them on server. You can code it accordingly.

```
public class NetworkStatusChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    boolean status = Utility.isInternetAvailable(context);
    if (!status)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Network Error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }
}
```

Put this in manifest.

```
    <receiver    
        android:name="NetworkStatusChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkStatusChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This might be helpful !!!!!

Comment: Can you please tell me how to call this receiver from activity?

Comment: No need to call it explicitly , as we had defined receiver in our manifest with intent-filters CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE and WIFI_STATE_CHANGED. This will call automatically by Android system when network state changed.

Comment: Thanks Akhilesh. Well i knew the same but had a little bit confusion.

Comment: Well Akhilesh,You need to change one thing in your code.You have to make your class public here..

Comment: @DeepakSharma You should select this as the top answer. For help on the database side of things, see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html .

Answer (score 2):

How about storing the data temporarily inside a [SQLite database](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) or [shared preferences file](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)?

You could do something like this to check if the connection is available

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

I would create an [Android Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that does this check in the background every few seconds/minutes and does the post if the connection is available.

Comment: Hey Edward!! I already know this method.But this is not the solution of my problem.Actually there is a button in my app.On clicking that button,some values are calculated and pass in the parameters to send them to server.Now suppose the internet is not available and i pressed that button for 5 times then in this case all the values which was calculated 5 times are stored in somewhere else and when the connection comes the web service will hit and all the data will be sent to the server.This is my actual problem.Please try to sort out it.well Thanks for ur reply :)

Comment: If you want to store the calculated data you need to make a database first. Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this case doing this:

1º Create a way to persist the Data to be posted, leaving place to a status column (sent/notSent). I used SqLite dataBase;

2º Create a communicator class that will POST the Data;

3º Create a IntentService that will check if that is any Data in the DataBase not Posted.

The following code is just for reference:

1º

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        //Start the IntentService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

//...

    private void sendData() {
            synchronized (this) {
                //Save the Data in local dataBase.
                DataToSend dataTosend = new DataToSend(foo, bar);
                dataTosend.save(context);
                //Pass the data to communicator
                communicator.sendData(dataTosend);
            }

        }
```

2º

```
//Communicator.class

    public void sendData(DataToSend dataTosend) {
    //Code to send the Data to the server

    //POST Request successfully:
    dataTosend.setAsSent();

    //POST Request failure:
    dataTosend.setAsNotSent();
}
```

3º

```
//IntentService.class

    //...

    private synchronized void sincroniza(String token) {
    //Check for dataTosend not yet send
    List<DataTosend> dataTosends = DataTosend.getNotSent(context);
    thatIsNotSentDataToSend = dataTosends.size() > 0;

    while (thatIsNotSentDataToSend) {

        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                for (DataTosend dataTosend :
                        dataTosends) {
                    //Send the data and mark as sent
                    communicator.sendData(dataToSend);

                    //If the comunicador send this data successfully, it will mark as sent (setAsSent() method).

                    //Clear the local DataBase
                    DataTosend.clearSentData(context);
                }
                //Verifies that there is still unsent Data
                dataTosends = DataToSend.getNotSent(context);
                thatIsNotSentDataToSend = (dataTosends.size() > 0);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```